# What are the ways/tools to compare 2 Windows installations and their KB updates?

Tags: wmi, configuration, knowledge-base

I have a list of machines, some machines throw

`System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR`

upon doing Windows Management Object's query,

`select Name, State, Started, Status from Win32_Service`

I suspect it is due to different KB installations on those machines. Is there any way to create a profile of that and compare KB updates of 2 given machines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save the output of all computername to a text file, then use PowerShell to generate list of hotfixes

```
$list = Get-Content <path to text file>

foreach ($cn in $list) {

$res = Get-Hotfix –cn $cn | Select HotfixID, Description, InstalledOn | `
sort InstalledOn

$res | Out-file $cn.txt
}
```

Then compare text file.